# How to merge properties inside object into one property?

Tags: javascript, object, merge, properties

I have object of orders

```
{
  someUserData,
  createdAt: 2019-11-05T18:32:25.199+00:00,
  total: 5
}
```

I want to achieve this kind of data structure:

```
{
  2019: {
   0: 5,
   1: 100
   total: 999
  }

}
```

2019 - year 
0,1 etc. - months, total value to the right 
total: yearly income

I've tried this:

```js
    calculateMonthlyRevenue = () => {
        const { orders } = this.state;
        const ordersMonthly = orders.map(x =>({
              ...x,
              year: new Date(x.createdAt).getFullYear(),
              month: new Date(x.createdAt).getMonth(),
            }
        ));
        const sumPerMonth = ordersMonthly.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            acc[cur.year] = acc[cur.year] + cur.total || cur.total;
            acc[cur.month] = acc[cur.month] + cur.total || cur.total;
            return acc;
        }, {})
    };
```

acc is giving me

```
{
  10: amount of all Novembers throught history,
  2019: I get the total amount, that is good but the data structure is not 
  what I need.
}
```

I've tried this:

```js
acc[cur.year][cur.month] = acc[cur.year][cur.month] + cur.total || cur.total;
```

and this

```js
acc[cur.year[cur.month]] = acc[cur.year[cur.month]] + cur.total || cur.total;
```

And I still get stuck.

Upper line of codes gives me

```
  9: amount
  undefined: amount
```

The last line of code throws an error (Can not read property undefined of 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string for getting year and month and use a default object with total for the year and a default value of zero for the month.

Add to both targets the total from the original object.

```js
var data = [{ someUserData: 'foo', createdAt: '2019-11-05T18:32:25.199+00:00', total: 5 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { createdAt, total }) => {
        var [year, month] = createdAt.split('-', 2);
        r[year] = r[year] || { total: 0 };
        r[year][month -1 ] = (r[year][month - 1] || 0) + total;
        r[year].total += total;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I feel dumb looking at how simple the answer is. Thank you